# Centralize some error messages from my form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Currently, I'm using `errorPlacement` to print error message for each input :

```
$('#my_form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         // Some code that print error below each inputs
    },
    ...
```

Then, I tried to centralize errors messages with `showErrors`, like this :

```
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
         // Some code that centralize each error for each input in one place
    },
    ...
});
```

It works fine, except that now I would like to centralize **only some errors messages of my form**, not all of them. Something like using `showErrors` only for inputs that I want to centralize, then `errorPlacement` for the others.

Comment: You'll have to use `showErrors` for everything, where you inspect the `errorMap` and `errorList` and conditionally place each message where you need it.

Comment: It was effectively what I did, I didn't find another solution at the moment. If you wan't, add this comment as an answer, I will validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something like using `showErrors` only for inputs that I want to centralize, then `errorPlacement` for the others.

One will always over ride the other.

You'll have to use `showErrors` for everything, where you inspect the `errorMap` and `errorList` and conditionally place each message where you need it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use text-align:center; property in css.

Comment: No, that's not what I expect.

Comment: "center" != "centralize"